# Profile system in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I am currently making an RPG management app for a project, and I am required to make a "profile" system, allowing to use the interface with three "sets" of variables, one for each game the app is designed for. Switching between profiles is done through pressing a button.

I was wondering if there already is a method created to facilitate my job.

If not, I am wondering if it would be a possiblity to create a class per "profile" (one per game), each containing the variables. That would allow me to call `[name of the game].[name of the variable]` instead of having three sets of variables.

Comment: You can create 3 different classes, gives you encapsulation and even if you want different variables for different profiles then you can add them in their respective classes. This is my suggestion though.